# Posting NULL Data to asp.net core controller using angularjs

Tags: .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

i am posting data from angularjs to .net core controller, but i am getting null values

StudentController

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AddStudent(Student stu)
        {
            if (stu != null)
            {

                    db.Students.Add(stu);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(stu);

            }
            else
            {
                return Json("Some Error Occured");
            }
        }
```

Module.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Service.js

```
myApp.service("myService", function ($http) {

    //get All Eployee



    // Add Employee
    this.AddEmp = function (Employee) {
        var response = $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'Employee/AddStudent/',
            data: JSON.stringify(Employee),
            dataType: 'json'

        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(Employee));
        return response;
    }


});
```

Controller.js

```
myApp.controller("myCntrl", function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.divEmployee = false;
    GetAllEmployee();
    //To Get All Records 
    function GetAllEmployee() {

        var getData = myService.getEmployees();

        getData.then(function (emp) {
            $scope.employees = emp.data;
        }, function () {
            alert('Error in getting records');
        });
    }



    $scope.AddUpdateEmployee = function () {

        var Employee = {
            Name: $scope.employeeName,
            Email: $scope.employeeAddress,
            Age: $scope.employeeEmail
        };
        console.log(Employee);
        var getAction = $scope.Action;

        if (getAction == "Update") {
            Employee.Id = $scope.employeeId;
            var getData = myService.updateEmp(Employee);
            getData.then(function (msg) {
                GetAllEmployee();

                $scope.divEmployee = false;
            }, function () {
                alert('Error in updating record');
            });
        } else {
            var getData = myService.AddEmp(Employee);
            getData.then(function (msg) {
                GetAllEmployee();
                alert(msg.data);
                $scope.divEmployee = false;
            }, function () {
                alert('Error in adding record');
            });
        }
    }

    $scope.AddEmployeeDiv = function () {
        ClearFields();
        $scope.Action = "Add";
        $scope.divEmployee = true;
    }

    //$scope.deleteEmployee = function (employee) {
    //    var getData = myService.DeleteEmp(employee.Id);
    //    getData.then(function (msg) {
    //        GetAllEmployee();
    //        alert('Employee Deleted');
    //    }, function () {
    //        alert('Error in Deleting Record');
    //    });
    //}

    function ClearFields() {
        $scope.employeeId = "";
        $scope.employeeName = "";
        $scope.employeeEmail = "";
        $scope.employeeAdress = "";
    }
});
```

Index.cshtml

```
<div ng-controller="myCntrl">

    <h1> Employee Details Page</h1>

    <br />

    <input type="button" class="btnAdd" value=" Add Employee" ng-click="AddEmployeeDiv()" />

    <div class="divList">
        <p class="divHead">Employee List</p>
        <table cellpadding="12" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <tr>
                <td><b>ID</b></td>
                <td><b>Name</b></td>
                <td><b>Email</b></td>
                <td><b>Age</b></td>
                <td><b>Actions</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                <td>
                    {{employee.id}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{employee.StudentName}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{employee.StudnetAddress}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{employee.StudentEmail}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span ng-click="editEmployee(employee)" class="btnAdd">Edit</span>
                    <span ng-click="deleteEmployee(employee)" class="btnRed">Delete</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="divEmployee">
        <p class="divHead">{{Action}} Employee</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Id</b></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" ng-model="employeeId" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Name</b></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="employeeName" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Email</b></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="employeeAddress" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Age</b></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="employeeEmail" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="button" class="btnAdd" value="Save" ng-click="AddUpdateEmployee()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
@*New record Modal addition..*@
@section scripts{

<script src="~/lib/angular/Module.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular/Service.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular/Controller.js"></script>

}
```

I just want you to check my POST function, i tried to check console.log as well its working fine i am getting data but when i check in asp.net core i am not getting data.

[image]

Comment: did you debug in angular service before posting it to service, if the values are there ?

Comment: yes values are there but just not passing in asp code

Comment: Would look at debugging the incoming request to see if it's something with trying to map the incoming JSON to the Student object (server side). Can be sure the network data looks right by looking in the chrome network tab when hitting the button, click on the new row for the post and can see details of data in the panel on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [FromBody] to you controller, like this:

```
[HttpPost] public JsonResult AddStudent([FromBody] Student stu)
```

The above is an example of what's called model binding.
Model binding is the process where  the MVC  pipeline takes the raw HTTP request and converts that into the arguments for an action method invocation on a controller.

You also need to add name attributes to the input fields of your form, like this:

```
name="employeeName"

name="employeeAddress"

name="employeeEmail"
```

The controller will read the name attributes and bind the input to the corresponding properties in your model.

Comment: I have added attributed still controller saving null valus

Comment: @WaqasRauf did you put  [FromBody]  by Student in the controller ?

Comment: You are welcome. I will edit my answer to include the full solution to the problem.

Comment: i need your little more help how can i contact you? because i have changes my all coding its not the same that i uploaded here

Comment: i will send you my code in email and will send you my issues

Comment: i have send you email

Comment: kindly i need to know how i can upload image in specific folder and save to database, after save how to show in view and from there i want to edit and delete option as well. kindly need urgent help

Comment: @WaqasRauf you need to address this in a separate question.

Comment: i couldnt upload this question dont know why

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass the values from repeater, you need to wrap it in existing object Employees, not pass it as single values

Comment: can you more elaborate please?

Comment: anyone help me with this please i just cant post data to controller